# What is the benefit of using ComparisonChain over Objects.equal() && Objects.equal() ... with Guava

Tags: java, equals, guava, comparisonchain

I have just started using google's Guava collection ([ComparisonChain](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) and [Objects](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html)).  In my pojo I am overiding the equals method, so I did this first:

```
return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.id, other.id)
         .result() == 0;
```

However, I then realized that I could also use this :

```
return Objects.equal(this.id, other.id);
```

And I fail to see when comparison chain would be better as you can easily add further conditions like so:

```
return Objects.equal(this.name, other.name) 
       && Objects.equal(this.number, other.number);
```

The only benefit I can see if you specifically need an int returned. It has two extra method calls (start and result) and is more complex to a noob.

Are there obvious benefits of *ComparisonChain* I missing ?

(Yes, I am also overriding hashcode with appropriate `Objects.hashcode()`)

Comment: There is never a reason to write `? true : false` in Java.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ComparisonChain` allow you to check whether an object is less-than or greater-than another object by comparing multiple properties (like sorting a grid by multiple columns).
It should be used when implementing `Comparable` or `Comparator`.

`Objects.equal` can only check for equality.

Answer (score 13):

ComparisonChain is meant to be used in helping objects implement the Comparable or Comparator interfaces.

If you're just implementing Object.equals(), then you're correct; Objects.equal is all you need.  But if you're trying to implement Comparable or Comparator -- correctly -- that is much easier with ComparisonChain than otherwise.

Consider:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
   final String field1;
   final int field2;
   final String field3;

   public boolean equals(@Nullable Object o) {
      if (o instanceof Foo) {
         Foo other = (Foo) o;
         return Objects.equal(field1, other.field1)
             && field2 == other.field2
             && Objects.equal(field3, other.field3);
      }
      return false;
   }

   public int compareTo(Foo other) {
      return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(field1, other.field1)
         .compare(field2, other.field2)
         .compare(field3, other.field3)
         .result();
   }
 }
```

as opposed to implementing compareTo as

```
 int result = field1.compareTo(other.field2);
 if (result == 0) {
   result = Ints.compare(field2, other.field2);
 }
 if (result == 0) {
   result = field3.compareTo(other.field3);
 }
 return result;
```

...let alone the trickiness of doing that correctly, which is higher than you'd guess.  (I have seen more ways to mess up compareTo than you can imagine.)

Comment: You can't have a `Comparable` accepting `null`, but if you're using a `Comparator`, then writing it as an `Ordering` lets you do `Ordering.nullsFirst()` or `Ordering.nullsLast()` to specify how it should order null values.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of overriding methods in your POJOs, I think of a few of Guava's tools matching with a few standard methods.

- `Object.equals` is handled using `Objects.equals` in roughly the manner you mentioned
- `Object.hashCode` is handled with `Objects.hashCode` like `return Objects.hashCode(id, name);`
- `Comparable.compareTo` is handled with `ComparisonChain` as below:

  ```
  public int compareTo(Chimpsky chimpsky) {
      return ComparisonChain.start()
          .compare(this.getId(), chimpsky.getId())
          .compare(this.getName(), chimpsky.getName())
          .result();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I would be careful when using Guava's `ComparisonChain` because it creates an instance of it per element been compared so you would be looking at a creation of `N x Log N` comparison chains just to compare if you are sorting, or `N` instances if you are iterating and checking for equality.

I would instead create a static `Comparator` using the newest Java 8 API if possible or Guava's `Ordering` API which allows you to do that, here is an example with Java 8:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.nullsLast;

private static final Comparator<DomainObject> COMPARATOR=Comparator
  .comparingInt(DomainObject::getId)
  .thenComparing(DomainObject::getName,nullsLast(naturalOrder()));

@Override
public int compareTo(@NotNull DomainObject other) {
  return COMPARATOR.compare(this,other);
}
```

Here is how to use the Guava's `Ordering` API: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained